# Laravel 5.2 sessions stop working (stop persisting) when I move the project from one PC to another

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

When I move my Laravel 5.2 Project from one PC to another, sessions stop working.
I have completely the same PHP installation and php.ini (the version doesn’t matter, I’ve checked it). And I run `php artisan serve` to serve my pages.

It’s obvious that the problem lays in the environment. But where exactly? The only noticeable difference is Windows’s version. I have the problem on Windows 10, and everything is ok on the Windows 7. Everything should work on both.

The bellow is a piece of code for reproducing the error.
The route returns ‘value’ on every request. But it should be ‘another value’ since the second one. And it makes me mad.

```
//Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/try', function (Request $request) {
        if ($request->session()->has('key')) {
            $request->session()->put('key', 'another value');
        } else {
            $request->session()->put('key', 'value');
        }

        return $request->session()->all();
    });
//});
```

I have a fresh installed Laravel 5.2 (5.2.29) with default parameters. I’ve checked all the parameters, and, as to me, they are fine:

*config\session.php*

```
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

*.env*

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

*php.ini*

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
```

Sessions are being written in `\storage\framework\sessions` alright, however for each request.

Comment: Try to remove `web` middleware if you installed or updated Laravel in last 2 weeks. Now `web` middleware applies automatically and if you're trying to add it manually, you can catch similar session related errors.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Really? They did it again? :)) I've tried your advice, and it didn't help. ((

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin can you cite this by linking to a commit please?

Comment: @BenSwinburne, I don't have a link, sorry. But you can compare 5.2.27 and older versions. Since 5.2.27 you do not have to include `web` middleware manually:  https://github.com/laravel/laravel/releases/tag/v5.2.27

Comment: @BenSwinburne I have a link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware , that now says "...Keep in mind, the web middleware group is automatically applied to your default routes.php file by the RouteServiceProvider."

Comment: Removing the 'web' middleware sure fixes things. Thanks @AlexeyMezenin